# The value displayed in Kdbg is wrong -- NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, kdbg

How can I test to see if the value of k is correct?

```
section .data
    k dw 5
    m dw 110
    rez dw 0 
section .bss
    tabela resq 3 
section .text
global _start
extern uslov
_start:
    mov qword [tabela], k
    mov qword [tabela + 8], m
    mov qword [tabela + 16], rez

    mov rbx, tabela
    call uslov
mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```

When I try to inspect the values of `k,m,rez` in kdbg the values of m and rez are just fine but the value of k is totally different, now at first i thought it was random, but it seems as tough it reads the value of rez as an 8 byte number instead of a 2 byte number and also reads in 6 more bytes taking in all the set 1's from m and rez which is wrong, so how can I display it correctly ?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Add the expression`(short)k` to the watch window instead.

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce this with your source (removing undefined references to `uslov`) when I compile using this command line:

```
nasm -f elf64 test.asm -o test.o
ld test.o -o test
```

Then, in GDB I can indeed see that `k` appears to have `sizeof(k)==4`:

```
gdb ./test -ex 'tb _start' -ex r -ex 'p sizeof(k)'
Reading symbols from ./test...done.
Starting program: /tmp/test

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004000b0 in _start ()
$1 = 4
```

This is because the only information the final binary has about `k` is that it's a symbol in data area. See:

```
(gdb) ptype k
type = <data variable, no debug info>
```

The debugger (KDbg uses GDB under the hood) can't know its size, so it just guesses the default size to be `sizeof(int)`. Even if you enable debug info in NASM via `-F dwarf -g` options, it still doesn't appear to put any actual debug info.

So, your only way to get the variables displayed with the right size is to manually specify it, like `(short)k` instead of `k`.

Comment: It's not a bug per-se, you (and the OP) simply didn't include *any* debug info for that symbol.  NASM doesn't magically associate sizes with labels based on `dd` / `dw` / `db` or whatever other instructions / pseudo-instructions you put after them.  (MASM even does this for implying operand-size in `mov symbol, 123`, again unlike NASM).

Comment: If you `p &k`, you'll see something like `$1 = (<data variable, no debug info> *) 0x600104`.  GDB's default interpretation is `int`.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah, I see. So you mean it's just a symbol in the symbol table, but not in the DWARF data? Will have to recheck.

Comment: Right, NASM does put everything in the symbol table with `-g`, even `.local` labels.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, I've edited the answer to reflect this.