# Casting label type in gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb

I am trying to learn assembly and I am using Ubuntu, I want to see the value of a label using GDB. Issue is that the label is one byte big and I cant cast it as just "p (byte)'label_name' ". And GDB does not seem to work if i dont tell it what the label size is.

Comment: You might be looking for `x/b`, depending on your exact situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p (char)label_name` works for me. GDB commands use C type names.  (Showing it as a number and the ASCII character it represents for `char`. C doesn't have a separate type for 8-bit integer).

C doesn't have a type called `byte`, so `(byte)foo` is an error.

As Jester says, `x /b &label_name` might be what you want to eXamine memory, especially if you want to see multiple bytes starting from a certain point.

Within GDB, `help x` and `help p` will show details on how to use it.

Related:

- [GDB shows error message when trying to print a variable in an Assembly program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250524/gdb-shows-error-message-when-trying-to-print-a-variable-in-an-assembly-program)
- [Address of an ASM label in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714563/address-of-an-asm-label-in-gdb) - how GDB gets symbol type info for debugging C programs.  Older GDB used to default to `int` or something, now it prints `'x' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type` like you were getting.
- [How to print <incomplete type> variable in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232744/how-to-print-incomplete-type-variable-in-gdb)